# Jenkins Plugin including Node and Node dependencies?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use a node tool, installed through `npm`, in a Jenkins plugin I am developing.

How do I specify my Plugin to install node and then `npm` dependencies? 
Or is this a separate instruction my user would have to do manually?

I have a feeling I'd have to do something in maven when I build my package but have a feeling there is going to be a lot more my user will have to do on their end.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [NodeJS plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs#). According to [Extend Jenkins, Dependencies among plugins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dependencies+among+plugins) it should be sufficient to add a dependeny to your POM:

> A plugin can declare dependencies to other plugins. When plugin X depends on Y, X can see all the classes in Y, as well as Y's libraries and dependencies. (That is, at runtime, Jenkins will set up classloaders in such a way that X classloader delegates to Y classloader.)

[...]

> [...] The maven mojos associated to the "hpi" packaging will use this information to put necessary information in the plugin manifest, which in turn is read by Jenkins at runtime.

Comment: Basically, create a dependency to this plugin. But how do i get node dependencies? Such as my specific node library, for instance, if I wanted to use lodash or something?

Comment: There's the [`<gropId>org.webjars.npm`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.webjars.npm) on maven Central. It contains [`<artifactId>lodash`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.webjars.npm%20a:lodash).

Comment: nice! I'll play around with this and see what it gives me!

Comment: `https://www.webjars.org/` so you can add a javascript library here and then absorb it. The best thing is you can add the ones you want. It'll also deploy its dependencies. Next part is learning how to use them. Hoping I can just call my node commands as processes or something.